# Which functions are interrupted by signals even with SA_RESTART?

Tags: c, posix, signals

Is there any reasonably complete list of which functions in POSIX are interrupted with `EINTR` when a signal is received or handled, even if there is no signal handler or if the handler was installed with `SA_RESTART`? Some examples:

- `select`
- `nanosleep`
- etc.

Answer (score 2):

tcsetattr is also not restartable, at least in Linux 2.6.18

Answer (score 1):

POSIX says:

> If the signal-catching function executes a return statement, the behavior of the interrupted function shall be as described individually for that function, except as noted for unsafe functions.

So, either you look through all functions individually or filter your man pages for EINTR and POSIX. I did the latter and got:

accept, 
aio_suspend, 
catclose, 
catgets, 
chmod, 
chown, 
clock_nanosleep, 
close, 
closedir, 
connect, 
dup, 
errno, 
exec, 
fallocate, 
fchdir, 
fchmod, 
fchown, 
fclose, 
fcntl, 
fflush, 
fgetc, 
fgetwc, 
fopen, 
fork, 
fputc, 
fputwc, 
freopen, 
fseek, 
fsetpos, 
fsync, 
ftruncate, 
getgrent, 
getgrgid, 
getgrnam, 
getmsg, 
getpwent, 
getpwnam, 
getpwuid, 
ioctl, 
lchown, 
lio_listio, 
lockf, 
mq_open, 
mq_receive, 
mq_send, 
msgop, 
msgrcv, 
msgsnd, 
nanosleep, 
open, 
pause, 
pclose, 
poll, 
posix_fallocate, 
posix_mem_offset, 
posix_trace_create, 
posix_trace_get_filter, 
posix_trace_getnext_event, 
posix_trace_open, 
posix_trace_start, 
posix_typed_mem_get_info, 
posix_typed_mem_open, 
printf, 
pthread_atfork, 
pthread_attr_getdetachstate, 
pthread_attr_getguardsize, 
pthread_attr_getinheritsched, 
pthread_attr_getschedparam, 
pthread_attr_getschedpolicy, 
pthread_attr_getscope, 
pthread_attr_getstack, 
pthread_attr_getstackaddr, 
pthread_attr_getstacksize, 
pthread_attr_init, 
pthread_barrier_init, 
pthread_barrier_wait, 
pthread_barrierattr_getpshared, 
pthread_barrierattr_init, 
pthread_cancel, 
pthread_cleanup_push, 
pthread_cond_init, 
pthread_cond_signal, 
pthread_cond_wait, 
pthread_condattr_getclock, 
pthread_condattr_getpshared, 
pthread_condattr_init, 
pthread_create, 
pthread_detach, 
pthread_equal, 
pthread_getconcurrency, 
pthread_getschedparam, 
pthread_getspecific, 
pthread_join, 
pthread_key_create, 
pthread_key_delete, 
pthread_kill, 
pthread_mutex_getprioceiling, 
pthread_mutex_init, 
pthread_mutex_lock, 
pthread_mutex_timedlock, 
pthread_mutexattr_getprioceiling, 
pthread_mutexattr_getprotocol, 
pthread_mutexattr_getpshared, 
pthread_mutexattr_gettype, 
pthread_mutexattr_init, 
pthread_once, 
pthread_rwlock_init, 
pthread_rwlock_rdlock, 
pthread_rwlock_timedrdlock, 
pthread_rwlock_timedwrlock, 
pthread_rwlock_unlock, 
pthread_rwlock_wrlock, 
pthread_rwlockattr_getpshared, 
pthread_rwlockattr_init, 
pthread_self, 
pthread_setschedprio, 
pthread_spin_init, 
pthread_spin_lock, 
pthread_spin_unlock, 
pthread_testcancel, 
putmsg, 
read, 
recv, 
recvfrom, 
recvmsg, 
scanf, 
select, 
select_tut, 
sem_open, 
sem_timedwait, 
sem_wait, 
semop, 
send, 
sendmsg, 
sendto, 
shm_open, 
sigaction, 
siginterrupt, 
sigpause, 
sigprocmask, 
sigset, 
sigsuspend, 
sigvec, 
sigwaitinfo, 
statfs, 
statvfs, 
system, 
tcdrain, 
tcsetattr, 
tmpfile, 
truncate, 
ualarm, 
usleep, 
wait, 
waitid and
write

Comment: But some of these always return -1 with `EINTR` if a signal occurs, and others return -1 with `EINTR` only when there's a signal handler installed without `SA_RESTART`. My question is about distinguishing these two cases.

Comment: All of the above functions, except msgop, semop, sem*wait, and select, are restarted if a signal with SA_RESTART is received and the signal handler returns. msgop, semop, sem*wait always return -1 with EINTR and the behaviour of select is implementation-defined (may fail or may be restarted).

Comment: Do you have a reference? I can't find if/where it's specified in POSIX.

Comment: [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) and [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04)

Comment: Since Linux is a very popular implementation, it is probably worth noting that it does not strictly match POSIX in this area.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959524/when-to-check-for-eintr-and-repeat-the-function-call#comment46931524_4960077

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wonders, the [manpage for `signal(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) has more detail on what is and what isn't restarted: