# SA_RESTART seems to have no effect on select

Tags: c, macos, select, signals

I am using select in one of my OSX programs to watch some file descriptors. I encountered the issue with child processes on Linux that select may fail with `errno` set to `EINTR`. On Linux I have encountered this using

```
struct sigaction sa;
::memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
sa.sa_handler = child_death_signal_handler;
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL);
```

Setting the `SA_RESTART` flag which will eradicate the issue on Linux. On OSX however, `SA_RESTART` is mentioned in the manpages, but it seems to have zero effect, as my read functions, etc, still fail with `EINTR` as `errno`.

Is there some way to make this work in OSX also?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which functions are interrupted by signals even with SA\_RESTART?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405297/which-functions-are-interrupted-by-signals-even-with-sa-restart)

Answer (score 1):

For Linux, SA_RESTART has no effect on select(2). See the manpage for signal(7):

```
The following interfaces are never restarted after being interrupted
by  a  signal  handler,  regardless  of  the  use  of SA_RESTART;
they always fail with the error EINTR when interrupted by a signal
handler:
...
* File descriptor multiplexing interfaces: epoll_wait(2),
  epoll_pwait(2), poll(2), ppoll(2), select(2), and pselect(2).
```

Comment: Quote from OP: "I am using select in one of my OSX programs to watch some file descriptors."

Comment: Finish reading the OP: "I encountered the issue with child processes on Linux that select may fail with errno set to EINTR. On Linux I have encountered this using...Setting the SA_RESTART flag which will eradicate the issue on Linux." This is false.

Comment: Thank you, please tell it Debian that they should change behaviour in their distribution :).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `SA_RESTART` does not have any effect on `accept()` if the calling ("accepting") thread is stopped/resumed with a signal.