# Should we care about EINTR when using sigwait?

Tags: c, multithreading, signals

In a multi threaded application all threads block all signals and a single thread does the signal handling in a loop with `sigwait`. Now should we consider `EINTR` after using system calls like `read` and `write` in other threads?

```
while (true)
{
    num = read(fd, buf, size);
    if (num == -1 && errno == EINTR)
        continue;
    else if (num > 0)
        /* handle the buf and read more */
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EINTR` is only returned if the system call was interrupted by a signal handler.  If all signals are blocked in the signal mask of the thread that's making the system call, then this can't happen.

Comment: See also this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959524/when-to-check-for-eintr-and-repeat-the-function-call#comment46931524_4960077