# What does return 0 mean when i write socket?

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, return-value

What does `return 0(or -1`) mean when i write(or read) socket in C on linux?

And Under what circumstances will these things happen?

and how to deal with `errno==EINTR`?

using `write() and read()` functions.

Comment: Read the description of the functions...

Comment: This question is off-topic because it exhibits zero evidence of prior research, and is already answered by the existing documentation.

Comment: I think he/her has the answer now ... with the burden of some downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 0 = means that the connection has been closed (EOF).
2. < 0 means an error (check errno for details)
3. > 0 means bytes read/written.

If you encounter an `EINTR` you can usually ignore it and keep on reading.

Comment: If you have a singal handler you might want to do something (depends on your code), but in the general case you can ignore it. I.e. if you have a timer, or want to interrupt your wait, shutdown, etc..

Answer (score 1):

`EINTR` indicates that operation is interrupted by a signal. You can ignore it and continue read/write. You can find more information [Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959524/when-to-check-for-eintr-and-repeat-the-function-call)