# How to manage reads with signals in C?

Tags: file, integer, signals, errno, eintr

I'm reading integers from a file in this way:

```
int v, num;
    for(;;) {
        v = read(fd, &num, sizeof(int));
        if (v == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in read()\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (v == 0) 
            break;
        [...]
    }
```

What does it happen if a signal arrives?
How can I manage errno == EINTR? Do I have to repeat read if errno==EINTR?

Comment: Check out this question and its answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959524/when-to-check-for-eintr-and-repeat-the-function-call .

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't mess with signals, you don't have to worry about it. Here's why: a signal's action is either terminate, ignore, or invoke a handler (or stop / continue, but let's ignore these), so, unless you explicitly caught any signal, then you will never have to think about `EINTR` - it will only happen if `read(2)` was interrupted by a signal handler that you set up, was invoked and returned.

If you caught a signal, then whether or not slow syscalls are automatically restarted is controlled by the `SA_RESTART` flag that can be set/unset in the `sa_flags` field of `struct sigaction` before setting the signal handler. If you want `read(2)` and others to automatically restart after the handler returns, then you must specify this flag to keep code portable (the default behavior varies across platforms).

Under some conditions, there are a couple of interfaces that are not automatically restarted even if `SA_RESTART` is set; refer to `man 7 signal` to see a list.

In case you're wondering: slow syscalls are syscalls that can block forever under certain conditions: for example, `read()`s from a terminal or socket, `open(2)` on FIFOs, `wait(2)` and family, file locking interfaces, some `ioctl(2)` calls, etc.