# Default signal handlers and EINTR

Tags: linux, unix, signals

Is it safe to assume that a system call will never return an `EINTR` error when all signal handlers are set to default action?

If not, is there a way to force this behavior (for example, handling signals in a separate thread)?

Comment: Related: [When to check for EINTR and repeat the function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959524/when-to-check-for-eintr-and-repeat-the-function-call). A comment there cites part of the signal man page: "On Linux, even in the absence of signal handlers, certain blocking interfaces can fail with the error EINTR after the process is stopped by one of the stop signals and then resumed via SIGCONT."